# number of netfilter queue

Tags: c, unix, network-programming, netfilter

I'm writing a some kernel module with netfilter's hook. The hook function:

```
uint main_hook(uint hooknum,
                  struct sk_buff *skb,
                  const struct net_device *in,
                  const struct net_device *out,
                  int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)  )
{
    struct iphdr *ip;
    struct udphdr *udp;
    if (skb->protocol == htons(ETH_P_IP)){
        ip = (struct iphdr *)skb->data;//skb_network_header(skb);
        if (ip->version == 4 && ip->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP){
            udp = (struct udphdr *)(skb->data + sizeof(struct iphdr));
            printk("[udp-catch] packet from %d to %d\n", ntohs(udp->source), ntohs(udp->dest));
            return NF_QUEUE;
        }
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Can I specify a number of queue? And if not then how can I find this number?

Comment: how do you mean number of queue? AFAIK you have 5 specific queues, which are meant for specific points in the packet flow.

Comment: The function prototype from libnetfilter_queue:  
`struct nfq_q_handle * nfq_create_queue (struct nfq_handle * h, u_int16_t num, nfq_callback * cb, void * data)`  
  
Quote from netfilter.org:  
*Creates a new queue handle, and returns it. The new queue is identified by num, and the callback specified by cb will be called for each enqueued packet. The data argument will be passed unchanged to the callback. If a queue entry with id num already exists, this function will return failure and the existing entry is unchanged.*

Comment: Can you explain why we need this u_int16 id?

Comment: [Also.](http://www.adslclub.ru/upload/img/2013-03/13-21480279727.png)

Answer (score 1):

## libnetfilter_queue and ip table

**Function documentation from libnetfilter_queue webpage:**

[create_queue()](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html#ga138190b535fa79202b0bc4177edb7fa7)

When creating your queue, the default vaule of num is 0.

If you have two queues running on the same machine, say one to send IP packets and another to receive, you need to create two queues with different numbers:

**send:**

```
qh = nfq_create_queue(h,  0, &cb, NULL);
```

**receive:**

```
qh = nfq_create_queue(h,  1, &cb, NULL);
```

For the IP tables to filter correctly you should specify the netfilter queue number:

**sender:**

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -d <dest ip> -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

**receiver:**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p all -s <src ip> -d <dest ip> -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

You can also check the manual for iptables and search for NFQUEUE.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: "When creating your queue, the default vaule of num is 0" - when I sending a packet from kernel-space to nf-queue, kernel sending this packet to queue with num 0 too. I want to force the kernel to send packets into another queue (with another num).

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem.
How many queues are you running on the same machine?
I'm no expert, but I think that if you want to do different things with the same iptable, you need to create different queues, like in my example above with one send and one receive.